# grails clean run-app on Windows bat file

Tags: grails, build, batch-file, build-automation, grails-2.0

`grails clean run-app` is not a command.

You need to run
`grails clean`
then
`grails run-app`.

If I create a bat file with the following:

```
grails clean
grails run-app
```

The script ends after clean. run-app is never called.

How can I run both in a bat file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Batch file below allows you to invoke it with several grails options like in your first example:

```
@echo off
:nextOption
   if "%~1" equ "" goto :EOF
   call grails %1
   shift
goto nextOption
```

For example, if previous Batch file is called CALLGRAILS.BAT, you can do this:

```
callgrails clean run-app
```

Of course, you may rename CALLGRAILS.BAT as you wish.

Answer (score 7):

```
CALL grails clean
CALL grails run-app
```

should do that.

The CALL gives batch a place to return to when the `CALL`ed procedure finishes

Comment: Adding CALL is exactly what I needed. Thanks. I gave you an upvote, but selected @Aacini's answer because it had the CALL command I needed and also a bat file to run them as args.

Comment: Hmm - if that's what you wanted, you could always try `for %%i in (%~1) do call grails %%i` I suppose...

Comment: Or even better, `for %%i in (%*) do call grails %%~i` which would allow you to execute `THISBATCH clean run-app "run-another with parameters" run-yet-another`

Answer (score 1):

You should also be able to use the below in command line:

```
> grails clean && grails compile && grails run-app

Or

> grails clean && grails run-app

Grails 2.2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to automate those 2 tasks into a single step, another option to is to create a global script in :

- *~/.grails/scripts/CleanRunApp.groovy* for Unix/Linux
- or *%USERPROFILE%\.grails\scripts\CleanRunApp.groovy* for Windows

In that case from any Grails project, you could run the following command:

```
grails CleanRunApp
```

---

Contents of the CleanRunApp.groovy file (Could be simplified but just as an example)

```
includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsClean")
includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsRun")

target(cleanRunApp: "Clean, then run app") {
    depends(cleanAll, checkVersion, configureProxy, packageApp, parseArguments)

    startPluginScanner()

    if(argsMap.https){
        runAppHttps()
    }
    else {
        runApp()
    }

    watchContext()
}

setDefaultTarget("cleanRunApp")
```